# Use custom row function instead of form arg in flask admin app

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

App is using Flask admin and has custom model view that inherits flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.
It implements all that is required and is working.

There is custom `row_actions.html` template with delete button containing `data-name` attribute that will be used to display custom delete message, e.g. `do you want to delete "John Smith"'s downloads?`.

Model view for each entity has their own `form_args`. Problem, not all models have `name` field.

I would like to be able to extract data-name from row, and for row to define it by implementing custom message.

So, instead of:

```html
{% macro delete_row(action, row_id, row) %}
<form class="icon" method="POST" action="{{ get_url('.delete_view') }}" id="{{ 'delete_form_%s' % row_id }}">
    ...
    <button class="delete_btn_submit" data-org="{{ **row.name** }}" title="Delete record" id="{{ 'delete_org_btn_%s' % row_id }}" onclick="return false;" >
        <span class="fa fa-trash glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </button>
</form>

{% endmacro %}
```

I want to use that custom function as below:

```html
{% macro delete_row(action, row_id, row) %}
<form class="icon" method="POST" action="{{ get_url('.delete_view') }}" id="{{ 'delete_form_%s' % row_id }}">
    ...
    <button class="delete_btn_submit" data-org="{{ **row.get_record_name()** }}" title="Delete record" id="{{ 'delete_org_btn_%s' % row_id }}" onclick="return false;" >
        <span class="fa fa-trash glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </button>
</form>

{% endmacro %}
```

I've read docs and I am not sure it is possible.